# Hector slam with turtlebot in Gazebo

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, ros-hydro, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to properly use Hector slam in simulation using a turtlebot. I'm using ROS hydro and Gazebo 1.9 on ubuntu 12.04. Once I spawned in Gazebo the turtlebot and the world I created, I use this launch file to start hector slam:

```
<launch>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" 
    args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.rviz"/>

  <include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch">
    <arg name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  </include>

   <arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame"/>
   <arg name="trajectory_update_rate" default="4"/>
   <arg name="trajectory_publish_rate" default="0.25"/>
  
 <node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
    <param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="map" />
    <param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="$(arg trajectory_source_frame_name)" />
    <param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_update_rate)" />
    <param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_publish_rate)" />
  </node>


  <node pkg="hector_geotiff" type="geotiff_node" name="hector_geotiff_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="nice -n 15">
    <remap from="map" to="/dynamic_map" />
    <param name="map_file_path" type="string" value="$(find hector_geotiff)/maps" />
    <param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="hector_slam_map" />
    <param name="geotiff_save_period" type="double" value="0" />
    <param name="draw_background_checkerboard" type="bool" value="true" />
    <param name="draw_free_space_grid" type="bool" value="true" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

The slam seems to work when I navigate the robot around, but I'm very surprised by the bad result compared to gmapping. It get lost very easily and the map is very bad. I would like to know if I set up something in the wrong way, or if it depends from the fact that I'm using a fake laser from kinect or maybe that the world in gazebo I created is challenging for hector slam.

EDIT:

If I move the robot only forward/backward the map is correctly reconstructed, but if I make the robot rotate on itself it prints 'SearchDir angle change too large' and it gets totally lost (sometimes it makes position jumps up to 1 meter and more!!).

This is the world I'm using in gazebo:
[image: image description]

Many thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95486/hector-slam-with-turtlebot-in-gazebo/) by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 808 on 2013-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It´s recommended to use gmapping if you´re using a Kinect and have a robot that provides odometry. hector_mapping does not work very well with the narrow FOV of the Kinect. See also [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/33933/kinect-doing-hector-slam/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-10-29**:
Thank you for your answer! Actually I was using hector slam as first step in simulation, but the final purpose was to try to use it for localization (in place of amcl) on a corobot (which has bad odometry and xtion sensor). I think I will search for another solution! thank you! :)